# Everyone should have a trapdoor

Tags: expressions

What does this phrase mean ? A getaway? A safe place? Saw in a sig [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=IxT3w0qz5mg#t=273%20video) I know she said something about homeless people (joke) but wondering if a deeper meaning too?

Answer (score 1):

She's talking about giving homeless people the privileges people with homes have. The vague part of the joke is that people with homes have some kind of "enemy" deterrent (security systems, guns, etc.) which includes trapdoors.

There isn't a deeper meaning to the phrase in question—it's just the joke that doesn't translate easily with everyone (even I had a hard time understanding it).

Comment: +1 Thank you. will wait 3 days to see if any more replies, before choosing accepted answer.